# PHP: Anyone know any tutorials for integrating facebook connect with a user login system?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, unix

I am building a site that would benefit from users signing up. Obviously adding a login with facebook makes it easier for users. Is there a good resource for how to implement this easily (in php) along side a normal user registration / login form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the facebook developer tutorial from http://developers.facebook.com/

and the latest facebook php sdk from https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

There are examples in the above sdk

Answer (score 0):

I simply add a column in the users table saying "facebook_id".

Upon connecting the application I get their facebook user_id and insert it into relevant or new user row.
Then I simply compare that id to the active one provided by the facebook javascript. You can fetch the facebook_id through the `$_COOKIES`-value.

If you find that `facebook_id` in the table, act like the user is logged in. Run the login function, if you have any.